# Ajax call always return error in springMVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
        url:'https://hybris.local:9002/store/verify?productCodePost='+productid,
        data : {notifyemail : notifyemail},
        dataType : "text",
        success : successmethod,

        error : function(data, status) {
            //alert("Error  "+status);

            $('#showbecomepartnerMessage').show();

         }
 });

alert("test values are"+notifyemail); 

document.getElementById('notifyemail').value='';

}

function successmethod(data) {

    if (data != null) {
        alert('Success');
        $('#showemailMessage').show();
    } else {
        alert('Error');
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public String verifyEmail(@RequestParam("productCodePost") final String code, final Model model,
            @Valid final AddToCartForm form)
    {


        System.out.println("Inside Verify method");
        final String email = form.getNotifyemail();
        System.out.println("Email is " + email);
        System.out.println("Product code is== " + code);
        final Boolean status = true;

        if (email != null)
        {

            System.out.println("Email id is" + email);

            notifyStockEmail(email, code);


        }


        if (status.booleanValue())
        {
            System.out.println("value of Boolean " + status.booleanValue());
            //return "success";
            model.addAttribute("success", "success");
        }
        else
        {

            //return "fail";
            model.addAttribute("error", "error");
        }
        return "success";
    }
```

In the above code i am doing a ajax call and calling a controller '/verify' and from controller i am returning a boolean value as true but everytime error method is executed in the jsp instead of success method.So how can i call success method by passing true value from controller as above.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error being returned by the server?

Comment: are you securing the app with spring security?

Comment: @David Inside console the value of retuned as true..but in ajax function it is calling error method...

Comment: @melli-182 no am not securing with spring security..

Comment: @User2413 ok! i think it could be dataType incompability, try removing dataType parameter from call.

Comment: @melli-182 i tried it but eventhough its not calling the succes method... playing with the code since morning but no solution till now..so last hope is stackoverflow,..

Comment: try using: $.ajax({
  url: "url",
 }).done(function() {
  yourMethod....
});  inestead of success and error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88217/discussion-between-melli-182-and-user2413).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String verifyEmail(@RequestParam("productCodePost") final String code) {

    //do what you want and return your status
    return "OK";
}
```

And you ajax call should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
        url:'https://hybris.local:9002/store/verify?productCodePost='+productid
 }).success(function(data) {
  successmethod(data);
});
```

Comment: Here how to send the data 'data : {notifyemail : notifyemail},' to controller??

Answer (score 0):

Despite your assertion, you are not returning a boolean value. You are putting a some String attributes named 'success' and 'error' in the Model and forwarding to a view named "success" and which or may not exist.

If you simply want the boolean value true|false written to the response stream then you can do this as below.

Add the @ResponseBody annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody boolean verifyEmail(@RequestParam("productCodePost") final String code, final Model model,
            @Valid final AddToCartForm form){

   boolean status = false;

   //check and set status.

   return status;
}
```

See:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

> This annotation can be put on a method and indicates that the return
>   type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not
>   placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name)

Comment: Can you elaborate about the status code as it is showing error to initialize the boolean variable,..

Comment: final boolean status = false;
  if (email != null)
  {
   System.out.println("Email id is" + email);
   notifyStockEmail(email, code);
  }
  if (status)
  {
   model.addAttribute("status", "success");
  }
  else
  {
   //return "fail";
   model.addAttribute("status", "error");
  }
  return "status";  is this the right way to set the status?? @Alan Hay